# i want to block touch input in other cell of table view controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I have table view controller with me. What I want is that I want to block inout in other cell(rows), after I click on one cell. for example If I have 4 cell with me then if user clicks on 1st cell then user input should be blocked in  2,3,4. Similarly if I select 2, input should be blocked in 1,3,4. How to do that?

Comment: Do you still want to be able to click that one cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Disable the user Interaction  in the Did select row Delegate Method of the UITableView

Comment: Indeed, but what if he you still want to be able to interact with that one certain cell because it has some controls on it or what not? But if u don't "[tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];" works just fine.

Comment: The method you need is `UITableView.didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexpath *)indexPath`. indexPath.row will give you the row number, so your code would look something like:

Comment: pseudocode -- if (!rowAlreadySelected) then { selectedRow = indexPath.row; rowAlreadySelected = TRUE; } else { if (indexPath.row = selectedRow) <do whatever it is you do when you get a click on the already-selected row. This may not matter.> } else { <do nothing> } }